# Is it possible to generate more than one page PDF report in R?

Tags: r, r-package

Can someone please suggest me which **R-package** should be used to generate a large report. This report could be more 50-60 pages or even more than that. Additionally, there is requirement to print these report with a nice look and feel i.e. different column colors, background, title and so on. I'll greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: RMarkdown http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/

Comment: R markdown is a good place to start.  I've generated reports over 300 pages long with Rmarkdown.

Comment: I forgot to mention one thing. I don't have any graph in report. it should be in tabular format only and report format is PDF.

Comment: If you learn Latex, with knitr you can do incredible things with tables and the document in PDF can be any number of pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will may be take some times but @lawyeR say true.

Sweave can be used with Rstudio, and it's a powerfull tool.
I use it evrytime to code and compile my pdf in the same time.
I have done my final report with it, more than 800 line of code with graph and many table.

My advice is try to learn LateX with the LaTeX companion and use it in Sweave with Rstudio.